# Importing text file with variable length sentence lines in R

Tags: r

I am trying to import and read a text file in R. This file has English sentences having variable lengths as follows:

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
Sed pulvinar enim ac maximus auctor.
Nunc tincidunt sapien quis magna ultricies porttitor.
Cras sagittis augue sit.

I intend to put each word in different column so that I could find out frequency of words used at first position, second position and so on. But I am not able to import the file in R. I would like to know if there is any way to read the text file and use " " space as a separator to insert words in different columns.

Comment: No statistical content -- suggest migration.  Hint: think of your file as space-separated values, with potentially missing values on some lines.  I.e. try  read.table("blah.txt", sep=" ", fill=T, strip.white=T)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an explicit example. The trailing period is preserved so this would need to be stripped off.  Also, there is a warning because the last line contains fewer "columns".

```
read.table("yourexampletext.txt", sep=" ", fill=T, strip.white=T, skipNul=T)
     V1        V2     V3   V4      V5        V6         V7
1 Lorem     ipsum  dolor  sit   amet.                     
2   Sed  pulvinar   enim   ac maximus   auctor.           
3  Nunc tincidunt sapien quis   magna ultricies porttitor.
4  Cras  sagittis  augue sit.                             
Warning message:
In read.table("yourexampletext.txt", sep = " ", fill = T, strip.white = T,  :
  incomplete final line found by readTableHeader on 'yourexampletext.txt'
```